# Windows 7 Sticky Notes

Tags: api, windows-7

Is there any public manual or article about Windows 7 Sticky Notes API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this, it could be useful:

http://www.niedermann.dk/2009/11/13/APIForStickyNotesInWindows7.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. The sticky notes data is stored as OLE stream in StickyNotes.snt. I tried reading the OLE stream with the PEAR OLE library without any luck.

[Decoding Window 7 Sticky Notes File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867903/decoding-window-7-sticky-notes-file)